# Relative positioning sprites

Tags: html, css, positioning, sprite

I can do

```
background: url(/images/sprites.png) no-repeat 0 -22px;
```

or

```
background: url(/images/sprites.png) no-repeat top center;
```

What if I want to place my sprite on top center? Like:

```
background: url(/images/sprites.png) no-repeat 0 -22px top center;
```

**UPD**

I have got a block with dynamic width. I want to put in its `top center` my image, that is part of sprite.

Comment: You can't do that. Simple as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use keywords such as `top center`, or explicit values such as `0 -22px`.

There is no way to use both at the same time.

(you can of course use one of each, for example `-22px top`)

Comment: Thanks, but `top -22px` doesn't work  :) while `10px center` works fine

Comment: Yeah, the order matters in that case (in most browsers), I've already changed it. Check the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#propdef-background-position

Comment: Isn't that the same as 50% 0?

Comment: In that case what will be the "top center" in percentage?

Comment: @avetarman: The same. Browsers allow either order, except in the case where keywords and values are mixed, from the spec I linked to: `If at least one value is not a keyword, then the first value represents the horizontal position and the second represents the vertical position.`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/D9uXx/

Comment: @thirtydot top center is the same as 50% 0. Right?

Answer (score 1):

```
background: url(/images/sprites.png) no-repeat 0 -22px top center;
```

This is invalid.

**top center** is the same as **50% 0**;

Can you describe what do you want exactly?